# How do I go about creating my own API/Framework/Libraries

Tags: winapi, api, frameworks, programming-languages, libraries

Some libraries are very obvious to me. I mean I can create the math, string etc libraries on my own. I don't understand how people create API's like OpenGL, OpenCV, DirectX, and MFC. I don't understand how to write them on my own like I write libraries to compute math and string functions. Are there any resources on the net that would teach me how I can go about doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Those kind of libraries are driven by two things.

1) is the domain that they're working in (notably GPU architecture, and their capabilities and limitations), and

2) the model of those capabilities as view by the API designer.

Simply, someone with some (ideally) reasonable understanding of the problem domain said "I think if you want to work with a GPU, I'd like the GPU to look like this", and came up with a model to present to the API consumer. Then the framework was written to convert that model view that the API designer contrived with the actual workings of the underlying mechanism (in this case a GPU).

Consider something like an Object Relational Mapper tool. Here, they're trying present an OO view mated to an underlying Relational representation.

The designers likely took some idea of what they wanted, tried them out to see how realistic it was do, and then started filling in the gaps and polishing the edges.

The way for you to start is to simply pick a domain which you have knowledge, but don't like how it works, and think "gosh, it would be better like this" and then start solving THAT problem. If things go well, you'll have some momentum and the process will likely get a bit more organic from there. But, ideally not too organic.

The hard part is putting your new API to work and USING it as someone who doesn't know the API, or necessarily the domain, would use it. Using it also gives you the opportunity to encounter the "gosh, it would be better like this" phase again.

Rinse and repeat until you're happy with the outcome.

Few paper designs survive contact with the actual development of the system. Some do better than others, but it's hard to know how an API is going to feel as a developer until you start using it.

So try a few apis on your own, study those you like, study those you hate and think how to make them better, and work on some proof of concept implementations to see how it goes.